# NgRx: selector gets called on the transition to a different page

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-router-store

I'm new to NgRx. After a bunch of reading, I added the router (`@ngrx/router-store`) to the app state to access the router parameter in the selector. I'm using a `CustomRouterSerializer` together with `RouterState.Minimal`. Since then I'm facing a problem which is when I'm navigating away from the detail page (*/hero/:heroId*) to list page (*/*) for example, the `getSelectedHero` selector from the detail page gets called which leads to other problems. Sure I can put null checks in...

But since I'm a beginner, I thought I'd better ask. It seems to be wrong that the `getSelectedHero` gets called on the transition to a different page. Sure the router state is changing, but?

I spent some time trying to find a solution that doesn't include an undefined check.

I created a "super" application that demonstrates the issue. I pushed it up to [GitHub](https://github.com/stevo-knievo/ngrx-sample-app) and to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/stevo-knievo/ngrx-sample-app/tree/stackblitz).

Here is the selector code from the detail page (*/hero/:heroId*) which gets called when navigating away from it.

```
export const getSelectedHero = createSelector(
  selectHeroesState,
  getRouteState,
  (state, router) => {
    const hero = state.entities[router.state.params.heroId];
    // FixMe: simplifies the problem... hero is undefined if you navigation for /hero/:heroId to / and following line will throw an error.
    console.log("getSelectedHero", hero, hero.id, hero.name); 
    return hero;
  }
);
```

In the detail page (/hero/:heroId) I use the following:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.hero$ = this.store.pipe(select(getSelectedHero));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you navigate to other routes the route parameter `:heroId` is not available.

when you navigate to a hero page, `.../hero/2` for example, the route param `:heroId` is available, because you have defined the route `hero/:heroId`;

When you navigate to the root page `.../` the route matches `""`, and that causes the route param  `:heroId` not to be set (it appears as undefined on your selector)

```
const hero = state.entities[router.state.params.heroId]; // <-- here "router.state.params.heroId" is undefined
```

Because your `getSelectedHero` uses selector the route state selector `getRouteState`, every time there is a route change and the subscription under `hero$` is active, the `getSelectedHero` will be called.

to resolve you could do:

```
if (router.state.params.heroId === undefined) return {};
```

Or you could move the selected heroId variable to the hero state, this way the navigation does not trigger the hero data selection

Comment: Thanks @thefabio for your answer! I'm aware that is the case. My question is why does the `getSelectedHero` selector get trigger when I'm navigation **away** from the hero page `.../hero/2`. In my example, you only can navigate to `.../` and on the `""` route are not params defined. I really don't understand why the selector `getSelectedHero` get execute when you are leaving the page.

Comment: A selector is triggered (assuming there is a subscription on it) every time the data they are selecting changes. Your `getSelectedHero` depends on the selector `getRouteState`. Every time you navigate, the data behind `getRouteState` changes, causing it to yield to all active subscriptions using it.

Comment: Thanks again @thefabio! I really hoped I was missing something here e.g. unsubscribe etc. Currently I'm using a guard block `if (!router.state.params.heroId) { return; }`. Returning `{}` will throw an error: `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Hero>'`. Again I'm new to NgRx but if I put the `selectedHeroId` in the hero state I need to manage it as well. That seems a lot for something so simple as a route parameter.

Comment: That's how ngRx recommends us to do it, with a selectedId variable. Have a look on https://ngrx.io/guide/entity , Which is the next step on the learning curve of ngRx